# CUDA 5 compatible with CUDA 4

Tags: cuda

CUDA 5 was released recently and I have been using CUDA 4 until now. So I was wondering whether the code I wrote in CUDA 4 will still run, if I install CUDA 5?

Is it completely compatible or partially? Will open source projects like [gpuocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/), that require CUDA 4, work with CUDA 5 too?

Thanks

Comment: Which OS are you using? Can't you have both CUDA 4.0 and 5.0 installed and test them both? As for the differences, it really depends on the kind of stuff you implemented. CUTIL has been removed in CUDA 5.0 for instance, so if you relied on it you will have to adapt your code. I believe that gpuocelot does not provide support for all the new features yet (it may still be experimental), and their FAQ does not refer to CUDA 5.0 at all. If this is a big constraint for you, you should send an e-mail to their mailing list.

Comment: In general, it should "just work". Note that while CUTIL was removed it was never part of CUDA and the message was clear that it was there simply to keep the example programs clean and tight, not for people to incorporate into their own applications. One caveat is that CUDA 5.0 removed certain string-based APIs. Most frequently this affects cudaMemcpyToSymbol() calls. You can check the CUDA 5.0 release notes here: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt

Answer (score 2):

There is not 100% compatibility between CUDA 4 and CUDA 5.

To choose just one example, in CUDA 5, it is [no longer permissible](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt) to use a character string to indicate a device symbol, which was possible 
with certain API functions in CUDA 4. Instead, the symbol should be 
used directly.

It's also been pointed out that the structure of the sample codes has changed significantly, which may impact your code if you are using elements of the sample codes.  However this isn't a true compatibility issue, in my opinion.

It's likely that the changes required to move a cuda code from CUDA 4 to CUDA 5 will be minor, if any.

Emulators often depend on unpublished characteristics of the CUDA runtime, and frequently only work with specific CUDA versions.  Check the emulator of your choice for any statements made about required runtime.